# Find out how closely the model fits the data

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting, data, dataset

I have an interpolating function

```
pfun[t]
```

and a data set in the form of

```
{{t,f}}
```

what can I do to get a numeric estimate on how closely the function fits the data ?

I read up on how LinearModelFit/NonlinearModelFit has options to display r-squared value, but this doesn't suit my case as I already have a function and don't need to fit anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like so, sum of squares of error:

```
 (pfun[#[[1]]]-#[[2]])^2&/@data //Total
```

Comment: decided to calculate as sum of abs values of error divided by number of elements, thank you